# AttributeError: 'spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'tokens_from_list'

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry,I don't know howt fix this error.

**'spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'tokens_from_list'**

Error of code is under.

```
import spacy
import re

regexp = re.compile('(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
en_nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=['parser', 'ner'])
old_tokenizer = en_nlp.tokenizer

en_nlp.tokenizer = lambda string: old_tokenizer.tokens_from_list(
    regexp.findall(string))

def custom_tokenizer(document):
    doc_spacy = en_nlp(document)
    return [token.lemma_ for token in doc_spacy]

lemma_vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer, min_df=5)
```

```
X_train_lemma = lemma_vect.fit_transform(text_train)
print("X_train_lemma.shape: {}".format(X_train_lemma.shape))

vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=5).fit(text_train)
X_train = vect.transform(text_train)
print("X_train.shape: {}".format(X_train.shape))
```

Please help me, a lot of time wasted to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Am I seeing it correctly that you are using SpaCy to tokenize while also overwriting its tokenizer with a custom tokenizer? And then you throw away everything except the tokenization?

If that is the case then you shouldn't be using SpaCy but instead just split by the pattern yourself. I would take a look at the pattern though and see if this is really what you want.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')

# print the substrings that match
print(pattern.findall("Sorry, I don't know how to fix this error."))
> ['Sorry', 'don', 'know', 'how', 'to', 'fix', 'this', 'error']

# print the substrings between matches
print(pattern.split("Sorry, I don't know how to fix this error."))
> ['', ', I ', "'t ", ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '.']
```

Generally if all you need is tokenization I would not recommend using SpaCy as it is quite slow and does a lot more than just the tokenization.

One alternative to SpaCy is [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/).

```
import nltk
sentence = "Sorry, I don't know how to fix this error."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens)
> ['Sorry', ',', 'I', 'do', "n't", 'know', 'how', 'to', 'fix', 'this', 'error', '.']
```

Comment: IT's doesn't make sense.
Maybe, I should chage
```
old_tokenizer.tokens_from_list
```
This sentences.
spaCy change grammer of tokenizer.
But , I don't know hoe to fix.

Comment: @masamichan Yeah but what are you trying to archive with your code? Why does it have to be SpaCy tokenization when you seemingly don't really need anything SpaCy-specific? You already split the tokens. Then feed it to SpaCy. Then pull them out of SpaCy again unchanged. Then throw away the rest of SpaCy. Why? You already have tokenization after using `.findall()`, just use this.

Comment: If it HAS to be SpaCy for some reason you shouldnt overwrite the attributes yourself. Better follow the official way to create a custom tokenizer in SpaCy, see documentation: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer